# Memory overflow when loading multiple files sequentially in python

Tags: python, pandas, memory, merge

I have a big dataset containing 100M records, where each record has two `id` columns as the foreign keys to two other files. After merging the datasets, each record have around 3000 columns. Since it is not possible to join this huge dataset with two other files, I have divided this dataset into 1000 files each containing 100k records. The following function reads a file and merge it with two other files:

```
def merge_data(path):
    db1 = pd.read_csv('../data/db1.csv')
    db2 = pd.read_csv('../data/db2.csv')        
    temp = pd.read_csv(path)
    temp = pd.merge(temp, db1, on='db1_id', how='left')
    temp = pd.merge(temp, db2, on='db2_id', how='left')

    return temp.drop('target', axis=1), temp['target']
```

Now, the following code tries to read these files sequentially:

```
for f in files_list:            
     Xdf, ydf = merge_data(f)       
     # processing Xdf, ydf
```

When I run this code, the first file is read without problem, but for the second file, the RAM overflowed and it starts to use the swap which slows down the process and freezes the jupyter notebook. I think if I can release the memory assigned to `Xdf` and `ydf`, the problem is resolved. For now, I have tried the `gc.collect()` and `del Xdf, ydf`, without any success. Any advice to handle this situation is appreciated.

Comment: How much is your Ram? Did you try making the tiles even smaller than 100k?

Comment: Did you run `del` first and then the garbage collection?

Comment: An alternative solution would be to do batch processing. Load a certain amount of lines from each initial file, merge them and write those lines into an output file. This way you never load much into memory.
Also don't use pandas for "big" data. IMO it always failed miserably performance and memory wise, just write things by hand, this is not complicated and will improve your processing speed dramatically in such scenarios. I suspect the strange behaviour you are experiencing is related to pandas memory management.

Comment: Also if you are using Jupyter to run your code, it seems to keep references to some old variables which prevents them to be gc'd.